# Cannot Upload Video in SwfUpload flash uploader in PHP

Tags: php, uploader

Cannot Upload Video in SwfUpload flash uploader in PHP.
I try script as the following already and not working :

```
$('#swfupload-control').swfupload({
    upload_url: "swf/upload-file.php?fname="+ escape($("#cbocateid").val()),
    file_post_name: 'uploadfile',
    file_size_limit : "102400",
    file_types : "*.*",
    file_types_description : "All Files",
    file_upload_limit : 5,
    flash_url : "swf/js/swfupload/swfupload.swf",
    button_image_url : 'swf/js/swfupload/wdp_buttons_upload_114x29.png',
    button_width : 114,
    button_height : 29,
    button_placeholder : $('#button')[0],
    debug: false
```

Please help .

Not display any errors on console.

No erorr. upload image is ok but video not working

Comment: What happens when you try to upload a file? Have you looked on your JS error console in your browser to see if you have any errors? More detail required - there's not much to go on there.

Comment: what is the error that u get?

Comment: No erorr. upload image is ok but video not working.

Comment: "Not working" is not enough information to go on. Anything in your JS error console (again)?

Comment: Actually, having had to deal with this before in PHP, I know exactly how frustrating it is, and for (I guess) beginner coders it's totally unexpected to have PHP just silently (without digging in logs) fail. Clearly, once you know, you know - but that's what we're here for ;)

Comment: He also said that images work ok, so the JS is fine. I'd bet (a bit) that it's the size of the file that's causing the prob.

Answer (score 0):

Check the size of the video in comparison to your max uploaded files size. If it's bigger you will have this kind of problem.

Quick snippet of code from kavoir.com to let you see the max upload size:

```
$max_upload = (int)(ini_get('upload_max_filesize'));
$max_post = (int)(ini_get('post_max_size'));
$memory_limit = (int)(ini_get('memory_limit'));
$upload_mb = min($max_upload, $max_post, $memory_limit);
```

Comment: max_upload=100
max_post=8
memory_limit=128
upload_mb=8

Comment: so if the file is bigger than 8mb, it won't work. did you understand those numbers, and how to fix them?

Comment: http://drupal.org/node/97193 this is for drupal, but the techniques will help you